# WPF Navigation Parameter Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, devexpress

Hello I have this xaml

```
<dxui:PageAdornerControl Header="Details" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <dxui:PageAdornerControl.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" >
                    <dxui:NavigationButton FontSize="14" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" Content="Customers" NavigateTo="CustomersPage"/>
                    <dxui:NavigationButton FontSize="14" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" Content="Categorys" NavigateTo="CategorysPage"/>
                    <dxui:NavigationButton FontSize="14" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" Content="Products" NavigateTo="GroupedItemsPage" NavigationParameter="{Binding Title}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxui:PageAdornerControl.HeaderTemplate>
    <dxlc:LayoutControl Padding="40, 10, 40, 10" ItemSpace="20">
        <dxlc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpace="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="20" IsHyphenationEnabled="True"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" FontSize="16"/>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
        </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
        <dxlc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" Margin="0,70,0,0" Height="20"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
    </dxlc:LayoutControl>
</dxui:PageAdornerControl>
```

The Bindings work fine with the TextBloks and Images but when i try to bind the Title to NavigationParameter it doesnt work and sends null parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of issue is that you've set the PageAdornerControl.Header property. This value is forwarded to the PageAdornerControl.HeaderTemplate and further to NavigationButtons DataContext. That's why your binding doesn't work.

You can clear the Header property (it is not actually used in your HeaderTemplate) or bind it to the SelectedItem property. As an alternative, you can use the RelativeSource binding:

```
NavigationParameter="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedItem.Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dxui:PageAdornerControl}}}
```